# Linking with --whole-archive flag

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, static-libraries

This problem is related to [This question I asked yesterday.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881325/variable-dissapears-in-binary-which-is-available-in-static-lib)
Now it seems that the linker flag --whole-archive forces the `test` object to be included in the binary. However, in linking with,

`g++ main.cpp -o app -Wl,--whole-archive -L/home/dumindara/intest/test.a -Wl,-no--whole-archive`

I get the following error:

`/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s`

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.a` files are meant to be statically linked, and so are not compiled with `-fPIC`. Consequently, you cannot make a shared library from it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the static lib. I agree that using `-fPIC` is pointless. How do I link correctly?